# How to display post and photo in html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to display posts and photos of users who are my friends. I used UNION ALL for this, but I don't know how to display it in html, because the posts look different and the photos look different. I am a beginner in php and have no idea how to do it.

```js
     $session = $_SESSION['id'];
 $query = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT photo.id, photo, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS autor, photo.date_to_add FROM `photo` join user on photo.user_id = user.id join friend on user.id = friend.request_from_id where request_to_id = :id and status = 'friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT post.id, comment, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS autor, post.date_to_add FROM `post` join user on post.user_id = user.id join friend on user.id = friend.request_from_id where request_to_id = :id and status = 'friend'ORDER BY date_to_add DESC");
        $query->bindParam(':id',$session, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the foreach like this :

```
$q = $query->execute();    

foreach  ($q->fetch() as $row) {
    print $row['autor'] . "\t";
}
```

You can read more informations here : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php

EDIT : as you asked me in comment, if you want to display your photos, you need to send your data in your view (if you're already in your view, it's the same) and do this :

```
<?php foreach($q->fetch() as $row): ?>
    <img class="fit-picture" src="/your/path/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>.jpg" alt="example">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

According 'photo' is the name of the image. If not, accord this below code with your name photo.

Comment: But I have to use <img> for display photo, and not for comment. How I can do it ?

Comment: @kowal20 What is the column for the name of your images ? Is it "photo" ?

Comment: @kowal20 I edited my post, I hope it will help you :)